# Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney as a loss function

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, optimization, loss-functions

I'm reading a [paper](http://cs.stanford.edu/~jure/pubs/linkpred-wsdm11.pdf) where the authors are using Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney loss function while minimizing an objective function. As the authors say in the paper, the role of the loss function is to give a positive value (penalty) when the input to the function is positive and it gives a zero otherwise. Here's the equation of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney loss function:

$\frac{1}{(1+e^{-x/b})}$

However when I used the function, it gave a positive value whether I gave it a positive value or a negative value! So what's wrong?! Could it be that the authors mis-wrote the equation? I wonder if someone knows this loss function and can clarify. By the way, it's also mentioned in the paper that when someone aims to maximize AUC then Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney is used.

Answer (score 1):

In the limit as b goes to 0 it has exactly the described properties.

So take a small value for b and you will get the desired result.

Hope that helps

Comment: This answer would really be helped by including a graph to show how this looks (perhaps for a couple of values of $b$ as you approach the limit).

Answer (score 1):

This function is also known as the logistic curve. The image below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)) shows you how it looks like.

It are the *asymptotes* that are 0 and 1. So for a sufficiently large negative number $x/b$ you can get as close to 0 as you want but you do not reach exactly 0.

[image: logistic curve from wikipedia]